# React native: Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode or parent node

Tags: react-native

Just started learning react-native,

I have created one separate file flexdemo.js and created component as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export default class FlexibleViews extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "powderblue" }}> </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 2, backgroundColor: "skyblue" }}> </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 3, backgroundColor: "steelblue" }}> </View>
            </View>

        );
    }
}
```

and App.js file is as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View, Image
} from 'react-native';

// import Bananas from './src/banana';
// import LotsOfStyles from './src/styledemo'

import FlexibleViews from './src/flexdemo';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // <Bananas name = "Tapan"/>
      <View>
        <FlexibleViews />
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

That gives me this error:

[image]

**Now if I try to run the code by adding flexdemo.js code into App.js then everything works fine.**

Changed The App.js like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';

export default class FlexDimensionsBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // Try removing the `flex: 1` on the parent View.
      // The parent will not have dimensions, so the children can't expand.
      // What if you add `height: 300` instead of `flex: 1`?
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
        <View style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
        <View style={{flex: 3, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: try deleting the comments in your render function

Comment: Deleting the comments inside render() fixed my issue. Thanks Chris

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Remove comments inside component.

Comment: I don't know. I was stuck with this error for a whole day and was unable to find any documentation for it. Finally, when this worked for me I thought of updating it here so some other beginner may not waste his time. I myself am a beginner.

Comment: The tutorial said it takes in some data and converts everything inside component to JSX for display of output. I must be simply ignoring the comments and trying to find some meaning out of it.

Comment: I dont have any comment or any // in the file.

Comment: I had a spare `>` after the opening root component.

Answer (score 40):

I want to give a more general answer here, because there can be several reasons for [the issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13653) returning the same error message. The three I have seen the most:

**1. Comments** might be the cause. But instead of removing comments **make
    them work**:

In the `return()`-part, variables need to be wrapped in {} like
    `{this.state.foo}` so wrapping the comments works fine...

```
    return(
        <Text> This works {/* it really does */}</Text>
    );
```

*...as long as they are not the first or last element in the return statement:*

```
    return(
      {/* This fails */}
      <Text> because the comment is in the beginning or end </Text>
      {/* This also fails */}
    );
```

**2. Conditional rendering** might be the cause. If myCheck is undefined or
    an empty string this can fail:

```
    const myCheck = ""; /* or const myCheck = undefined */
    return(
      {myCheck && <MyComponent />}
    );
```

*but adding double negation !! works:*

```
    const myCheck = ""; /* or const myCheck = undefined */
    return(
      {!!myCheck && <MyComponent />}
    );
```

**3. Whitespaces** (or actually any strings) *within* a component can cause
    this, if not in a `<Text>`-Component:

*Text in a View for example:*

```
    /* This fails */
    return(
      <View>it really does</View>
    );
```

*But also the tiny space between two components:*

```
    /* <View>*Space*<Text> fails: */
    return(
      <View> <Text>it really does</Text> </View>
    );
```

*But works if in a newline:*

```
    return(
      <View>
        {/* This works */}
        <Text>surprisingly it does</Text>
      </View>
    );
```

Unfortunately these pitfalls do not always lead to errors. Sometimes they work. I guess this depends on which of all those many tools/libraries/components you use and their versions in your app.

Comment: This error is like my wife, it won't tell me why it's mad at me. A line number would be great!

Comment: I found that also *&nbsp;* (instead of space) causes the problem

Comment: I was having the same error and my reason was #2. Added double-negation and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: #2 as well. Lifesaver answer.

Comment: I had this error as I have put a component between `<Text>` and `</Text>`. Correcting that removed the error.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to reproduce the issue with the code you provided. The solution is twofold:

1. In your flexdemo.js file you should remove the whitespaces from within the `<View>` tags. They are considered as text, and text is only allowed inside a `<Text>` component. I'd recommend making your `<View>` tags self closing until they have some content, to stay away from this issue in the future, like so:

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import { View } from 'react-native';

   export default class FlexibleViews extends Component {
     render() {
       return (
         <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
           <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'powderblue' }} />
           <View style={{ flex: 2, backgroundColor: 'skyblue' }} />
           <View style={{ flex: 3, backgroundColor: 'steelblue' }} />
         </View>
       );
     }
   }
   ```

   This will render your components but still be faulty, as you wont see anything on the screen.
2. To get your flexible shades of blue to appear you'll either have to add flex to the `<View>` component in your App.js file or(depending on what your next steps are, I guess) remove it and render your `<FlexibleViews>` as the root component, since it is basically a `<View>` component with some children anyway.

Comment: Yup sometimes , this issues caused by whitespace in your parent, me also facing this issue due to white space.

Comment: ` text is only allowed inside a <Text> component` helps me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `if else` statement in your `render()` function use **`!!`** like this:

```
{!! (this.state.your_state) &&
   <View>
        <Text>Your Text</Text>
   </View>
}
```

instead of:

```
{(this.state.your_state) &&
    <View>
         <Text>Your Text</Text>
    </View>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I downgrade react native version, then I got a different error, basically what it was I had a simple string within a view, something like this:

```
<View>
    MyComponent
</View>
```

I had to wrap the string with a text component like this:

```
<View>
    <Text>MyComponent</Text>
</View>
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

```
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "powderblue" }}> </Text>
            <Text style={{ flex: 2, backgroundColor: "skyblue" }}> </Text>
            <Text style={{ flex: 3, backgroundColor: "steelblue" }}> </Text>
        </View>
```

1. Make use Component hierarchy should be maintain, for example all components like Text, ListView, TextInput etc should be wrapped inside the parent component that is View. 
   lets see the below example :

   < View >
       < Text >
          CORRECT
       < / Text >
   < / View >
2. Make sure all the Component tag should be closed properly.
3. Make sure unnecessary semicolons should be removed from the react native layout components & functions.

https://www.skptricks.com/2018/08/react-native-cannot-add-child-that.html

Answer (score 1):

This error is usually from one of below mistakes

- Remove unnecessary comments and remove comments from return function.
- check for proper variable name.
- check for unintended semicolon or any wrong syntax

Answer (score 1):

Delete the comment in the return block "// "
I encountered the same problem when I accidentally add a ';' in the return block, the iOS is work well, but the Android has this bug information

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had small () brackets around one of my view which was causing error.

```
({renderProgress()})
```

Removing small brackets worked for me.

`{renderProgress()}`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a condition in my render function that resulted in evaluating 0.

It seems that 0 && 'some jsx' breaks in newer versions of react native.

**Error Example:**

```
render(){
   return <View>
              {this.state.someArray.length && <View>...</View>}
      </View>
}
```

Although this should be valid javascript and works in react since 0 is falsey, It crashes in react native, not sure why but it works with a little refactoring as:

**Working Example:**

```
render(){
   return <View>
              {this.state.someArray && this.state.someArray.length> 0 && 
              <View>...</View>}
          </View>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semi-colon when rendering a method in

`<View style={styles.container}>
  {this.renderInitialView()} //semi-color should not be here
</View>`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue just now and solved it by removing the comments that I have made while editing the project in android studio and over there the comment's shorotcut just adds /* and */ but actually for react native the commented code should be enclosed with starting and end of curly braces, for example following would be an invalid comment:

```
/*<Text style={styles.pTop}>
 {
    this.state.response.map((index, value) => {
    return index.title;
    })
 }
 </Text>*/
```

And the following will be a valid one:

```
{/*<Text style={styles.pTop}>
 {
    this.state.response.map((index, value) => {
    return index.title;
    })
 }
 </Text>*/}
```

you see there is just one minor difference of enclosing the comment in curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs if you have comments in your render() return() function. Remove all comments in your return function when rendering JSX

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had written `<TextInput>` in the `<Text>` tag.
Below is wrong. It will give error for child.

```
<text>
  <TextInput style={styles.textinput} 
        textcolor
          placeholder = 'user id'
          placeholderTextColor = 'gray'
   />
</Text>
```

solution.

```
 <Text> hello </Text>
 <TextInput style={styles.textinput} 
        textcolor
          placeholder = 'user id'
          placeholderTextColor = 'gray'
  />
```

you have to write separate tag.

So any tag you have written in another tag this error can come.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note you are answering a very old and already answered question. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).